# mongostat auto stop command needed for linux

Tags: linux, mongodb

I am using mongodb and for finding the statistics I am using the command mongostat --host localhost --port 27017 --all
  in which i am getting the statistics. My problem is that I am using the same command in writing inside a script and I want the same to stop automatically after desired time say 5 seconds like giving the time interval. Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

`mongostat` has a `-n` (aka `--rowcount`) option you can use:

```
-n [ --rowcount ] arg (=0) number of stats lines to print (0 for indefinite)
```

So if you want to get 5 seconds of stats (using the default interval of 1 second):

```
mongostat --host localhost --port 27017 --all -n 5
```

Or more concisely, if you are using the default host and port:

```
mongostat --all -n 5
```

To see all command line options for your version of `mongostat`:

```
mongostat --help
```

Answer (score 0):

mongostat by default gets one iteration per second. You can use the "--rowcount 5" option which will terminate mongostat after the 5th iteration. I am doing a similar thing but my iteration runs only once every 60 seconds and inserts the output into a separate db.